# Does state reset when I navigate back to the previous screen in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a class which returns different screens depending on the state `screen`, so, now I have the need to create another class in another file but I am not very sure if I can navigate back to the screen without reseting the state.

Suppose I am in screen 4 (class A) and I clicked a button which sends me to another screen which will be in Class B, and now I want to go back to screen 4
(Class A).

Whenever I tried something like this it did not change, but I wanna know if that was just luck or it really does not reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State always gets updates as the value changes in it which directly renders the components. States are limited to particular screen/class only. Once you change the class yes they do get reset.

Comment: I guess I will continue working in the same class with all other screens. IDK if that's the right approach but seems easier.

Comment: what actually you are aiming to implement?

Comment: I have started designing all the screens in a single class but I thought of moving on to another class for a specific screen but I think I will drop the idea out.